# Tie a minor-mode to a particular major mode

Tags: keymap, hooks, major-mode, minor-mode

I'm writing an extension to a major mode (`coq-mode`) that adds extra features, plus a few keybindings.

To makes it easy to disable or redefine these keybindings, I packaged them in a keymap. That keymap is tied to a `myplugin-keybindings-minor-mode` minor mode, which gets enabled in `coq-mode-hook`.

Most of these keybindings do not make sense outside of `coq-mode`. Yet when I open new buffers from a `coq-mode` buffer, `myplugin-keybindings-minor-mode` is enabled in the newly opened buffer.

How do I prevent this from happening? **How do I tie my minor mode to `coq-mode`, so that `myplugin-keybindings-minor-mode` is never active when `coq-mode` isn't?** Altenatively, which other approach should I use?

EDIT:

The minor mode is enabled by using `(add-hook 'coq-mode-hook #'myplugin-initialize)`, and `myplugin-initialize` calls `(myplugin-keybindings-mode 1)`.

EDIT2: You can see the problem I'm talking about by opening a `diff-mode` buffer (`C-x f test.diff`), and then running `M-x shell` from it. The shell buffer had the `Diff-Auto-Refine` mode on, inherited from the diff buffer. This isn't a problem for `Diff-Auto-Refine`, but it is for `myplugin-keybindings`

Comment: How do you "open new buffers from a `coq-mode` buffer" -- i.e., find-file, display-buffer, clone the buffer and incorporate everything from the original buffer, etc.?  Is your minor-mode attached to a major-mode hook for all new buffers opening in that particular major-mode -- e.g., if major-mode xyz then (coq-mode 1)?  Is your minor-mode global -- e.g., `:global t` -- instead of local, and that's the problem you wish to resolve?

Comment: My minor mode is local, not global. New buffers are opened e.g. using `find-file`, or `shell`, or `ido-switch-buffer`.

Comment: Unless you have a global activation for your `myplugin-keybindings-mode` -- e.g., `:global t` or `(define-globalized-minor-mode  . . .)`, it should only be active in buffers that have a major-mode of `coq-mode`.  Until you track down the problem, you can use `(unless (eq major-mode 'coq-mode) . . .)` as a wrap-around for your minor mode.

Comment: @lawlist: I've edited the post. For an example of the behaviour I want to avoid, open a diff-mode buffer, and run `M-x shell` from it. The shell buffer will have `Diff-Auto-Refine` minor mode enabled, inherited from the diff buffer. The same happens with my keybindings mode, and I want to avoid that.

Comment: @lawlist Is that really the case? It's not a globalized minor mode, but it's definitely inherited by buffers opened from a buffer where it's already active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?:

```
(define-minor-mode myplugin-keybindings-mode
"A minor-mode for . . . . ."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter " myplugin"
  :keymap nil
  :global nil
  :group 'coq-mode
  (cond
    ((and
        myplugin-keybindings-mode
        (eq major-mode 'coq-mode))
      (my-main-function)
      ;; *** insert additional stuff
      (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
        (message "Turned ON `myplugin-keybindings-mode`.")))
    (t
      ;; *** insert additional stuff
      (when (called-interactively-p 'any)
        (message "Turned OFF `myplugin-keybindings-mode`.")))))

(defun my-main-function ()
  (when
      (and
        myplugin-keybindings-mode
        (eq major-mode 'coq-mode))
    (message "Hello-world!")
    ;; insert more stuff
  ))
```

Comment: Thanks! That put me on the right track. I had messed up the order of the arguments, and had set `init-value` to `t`.